# Empty input selector in jquery dont work on edited values

Tags: jquery

Given the html of:

```
<input type="text" name="name1" value="">
```

I run `console.log( $('input[value='']).length );` and get 1.

If I then enter a value in the field and run `console.log( $('input[value='']).length );` again I still get 1. What gives? Do selectors only work on the original values of forms?

If I set the value from start, i.e.

```
<input type="text" name="name1" value="">
```

... I get the expected 0 when I run `console.log( $('input[value='']).length );`

There's a workaround for jquery < 1.8.3, (using `input:text[value='']` instead), but >= 1.9, this doesn't work either.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nZ27z/10/

Comment: There is a difference in property and attribute

Comment: FWIW, found this in the jquery upgrade guide - http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When someone types in a field, the value *property* changes, not the value *attribute*.

You can do something like this:

```
var emptyCount = $('input').filter(function() { 
    return this.value === ''; 
}).length;
```

Comment: So when I change the value, manually by entering something in the field or automatically in jquery, I'm only changing the property. Does that make attributes immutable? Or can you change attributes too? (And what's the point of the separation? =) Just curious.

Comment: You can change attributes, using `.attr()`. Here is an SO question with several very detailed answers on the difference between attributes and properties, and `.attr()` and `.prop()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 0):

With this code if u change the value of the imput your length after running it again will change.

```
console.log($( "input[name='name1']").val().length);
```